# Is it possible to decorate function via sinon.stub

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

For example, I have the object like below:

```
var obj = {
    someMethod: function() {
        // base functionality...
    }
};
```

In an unit test I'd like to create stub for the `obj.someMethod` method:

```
var func = function() {
    // new functionality...
};
var stub = sinon.stub(obj, "someMethod", func);
```

The `func` should not completely replace the `obj.someMethod`. It should decorate the `obj.someMethod`. Currently, I use the following approach:

```
var base = obj.someMethod;
var func = function() {
    base();
    // new functionality...
};
var stub = sinon.stub(obj, "someMethod", func);
```

Does sinon provide the same functionality out of the box?

Comment: No, it does not. But chances are you're approaching this the wrong way, the whole purpose of stubbing is to avoid calling the original method. What do you want to test?

Comment: Yeah, I've felt something bad in the approach I've described)) I just want to test some js function, but there are some smells in my code. Looks like, I need to refactor it, and next use stub like it should.